# Prove isomorphism for a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Show that $M\simeq \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ considering them as $R$-modules and $R\simeq \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,R)$ considering them as rings.

I couldn't find a way to define the isomorphism.

Comment: Well observe that we have a map $\phi:Hom_{R}(R, M)\to M$ given by $\phi(\psi)=\psi(1)$.

Comment: @user26857 I'm sorry but I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: It is enough that you define $\phi(1)$. Since $\phi$ is $R$-module homomorphism, we can extent to $R$. Hence $\Phi:\rm{Hom}$$(R,M)\rightarrow M$ where $\Phi$, carries  $\phi$ to $\phi(1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Now, about this part: "Since $\phi$ is $R$-module homomorphism, we can extent to $R$", could do explain a bit further?, would this work to prove $R\simeq \operatorname{Hom_R}(R,R)$?

Comment: For instance, you want to define $\phi(r)$ by using $\phi(1)=m$. So u can see that $\phi(r)=r\phi(1)=r.m$. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes!, I got it!

Answer (score 2):

Verify that $\hom(R,M) \to M, \phi \mapsto \phi(1)$ is a map, that $M \to \hom(R,M), m \mapsto (r \mapsto rm)$ is a map, and that they are inverse to each other.